# How to declare a union of tuple types so that after destructuring, the types of the variables still remain associated

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to define the type of tuples so that the types are inferred as described in the comments in the code example below?

```
declare const tuples: [number, null] | [null, number];

const [a, b] = tuples;

const fun = () => {
  if (a === null) {
    const c = b; // How to define type of 'tuples' so that 'c' infers as 'number'???

    return;
  }

  const d = b; // How to define type of 'tuples' so that 'd' infers as 'null'???
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unfortunate answer is *don't destructure the array until you have determined which type it is*.

By destructuring before you have determined which half of the type union you are actually working with, you break the relationship between the two elements and their corresponding types. With the initial type of `[number, null] | [null, number]`, if you access the first element without first checking which of the two array types it is, TypeScript must assign a type for the value that would match to *both* array types, eg: `number | null`, and critically, TypeScript considers the type of new variable `a` independently of the type for variable `b`.

The fix is to wait on destructuring until after you've checked the array:

```
declare const tuples: [number, null] | [null, number];

const fun = () => {
  if (tuple[0] === null) {
    const [a, b] = tuples
    const c = b; // c has type number

    return;
  }

  const [a, b] = tuples
  const d = b; // d has type null
}
```

Comment: This is a [well known inconvenience](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32639) and you can track progress toward a possible eventual solution on [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12184) / [this pull](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/44730).